# search for a set of values on rows (& not |) from a column

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, row

I'm new to python and I'm trying to find the entries from the first column that have in the second column all the entries I'm searching for. ex: I want entries {155, 137} and I expect to get 5 and 6 from column id1 in return.

```
id1  id2
----------
1.    10
2.    10
3.    10
4.    9
5.    137
5.    150
5.    155
6.    10
6.    137
6.    155
....
```

I've searched a lot on google, but couldn't solve it. I read these entries from an excel, I tried with multiple for loops, but it doesn't look nice because I'm searching for a lot of entries

I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('path/temp.xlsx') #now I have two Columns and many rows

d1 = df.values.T[0].tolist()

d2 = df.values.T[1].tolist()

d1[d2.index(115) & d2.index(187)& d2.index(276) & d2.index(239) & d2.index(200) & d2.index(24) & d2.index(83)]
```

and it returned 1

I started to work this week, so I'm very new

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two lists for both the IDs (i.e. one list for id1, and one for id2), and the lists correspond to each other (that means, the value at index `i` in list1 corresponds to the value at index `i` of list2).

If that is your case, then you simply have to find out the index of the element, you want to search for, and the corresponding index in the other list will be the answer to your query.

To get the index of the element, you can use Python's inbuilt feature to get an index, namely:

`list.index(<element>)`

It will return the zero-based index of the element you wanted in the list.

To get the corresponding ID from id1, you can simply use this index (because of one-one correspondence). In your case, it can be written as:

`id1[id2.index(137)] #it will return 5`

**NOTE:**
`index()` method will return the index of the first matching entry from the list.

Comment: I need to return all of the IDs from the first column, that have all the elements I search for in the second column. I tried to transform the two read columns from my original excel table into two lists and then use id1[id2.index(137) & id2.index(138)  & ...]  but it just returned "1"

Comment: If you're comfortable in working in Pandas, then the other answer will be well suited/easy to implement. Else, you can probably update the question and add the piece of code which returns 1. I will be happy to review it.

Answer (score 0):

best to use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Random data

```
n = 10
I = [i for i in range(1,7)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id1': [Id[np.random.randint(len(I))] for i in range(n)],
                    'Id2': np.random.randint(0,1000,n)})

df1.head(5)
   Id1  Id2
0    4  170
1    6  170
2    6  479
3    4  413
4    6   52
```

Query using

```
df1.loc[~df1.Id2.isin([170,479])].Id1
Out[344]: 
3    4
4    6
5    6
6    3
7    1
8    5
9    6
Name: Id1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: as I start with an excel table with two columns, do I need to transform them in two lists and then join them again in order to use this df1.loc[~df1.Id2.isin([170,479])].Id1?

Comment: @cribb No. You simply write `df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\file.csv')` instead of `df1 = pd.DataFrame(...` as this is just random data I made (I was lazy and didn't want to copy your example). 
'C:\folder\file.csv' is just generic, replace that with your file path and use \ or //

As for the list `[170,479]` that you can declare outside the code

Comment: @cribb Also the file doesn't have to be in the C  drive. I suggest you stick to .csv for your excel

Answer (score 0):

for now, I've solved it by doing this

[image]